# Replace section of text with only knowing the beginning and last word using Python

Tags: python, text, replace

In Python, it possible to cut out a section of text in a document when you only know the beginning and end words?

For example, using the bill of rights as the sample document, search for "Amendment 3" and remove all the text until you hit "Amendment 4" without actually knowing or caring what text exists between the two end points.

The reason I'm asking is I would like to use this Python script to modify my other Python programs when I upload them to the client's computer -- removing sections of code that exists between a comment that says "#chop-begin" and "#chop-end". I do not want the client to have access to all of the functions without paying for the better version of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Python's [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module.

I wrote this example script for removing the sections of code in file:

```
import re

# Create regular expression pattern
chop = re.compile('#chop-begin.*?#chop-end', re.DOTALL)

# Open file
f = open('data', 'r')
data = f.read()
f.close()

# Chop text between #chop-begin and #chop-end
data_chopped = chop.sub('', data)

# Save result
f = open('data', 'w')
f.write(data_chopped)
f.close()
```

Comment: thank you!  the other two examples didn't work for some reason

Comment: As you have neither `^` nor `$` in the pattern, specifying re.MULTILINE is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
import re

string = re.sub('#chop-begin.*?#chop-end', '', string, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

`.*?` will match all between.

Comment: The manual says `re.sub(pattern, repl, string[, count, flags])` ... you have the second and third args in the wrong order.

Comment: because I didn't consider that such an edit fell within the guidelines """clarify meaning without changing it, correct minor mistakes"""

Answer (score 0):

With data.txt

```
do_something_public()

#chop-begin abcd
get_rid_of_me() #chop-end

#chop-beginner this should stay!

#chop-begin
do_something_private()
#chop-end   The rest of this comment should go too!

but_you_need_me()  #chop-begin  
last_to_go()
#chop-end
```

the following code

```
import re

class Chopper(object):
    def __init__(self, start='\\s*#ch'+'op-begin\\b', end='#ch'+'op-end\\b.*?$'):
        super(Chopper,self).__init__()
        self.re = re.compile('{0}.*?{1}'.format(start,end), flags=re.DOTALL+re.MULTILINE)

    def chop(self, s):
        return self.re.sub('', s)

    def chopFile(self, infname, outfname=None):
        if outfname is None:
            outfname = infname

        with open(infname) as inf:
            data = inf.read()

        with open(outfname, 'w') as outf:
            outf.write(self.chop(data))

ch = Chopper()
ch.chopFile('data.txt')
```

results in data.txt

```
do_something_public()

#chop-beginner this should stay!

but_you_need_me()
```

Comment: This line in your code `def __init__(self, start=r'\s*#chop-begin\b', end=r'#chop-end\b.*?$'):` would be mangled if run through your code. Your two subpatterns should start with `^` so that they match only at the start of a line.

Comment: @John Machin: on considering the question further I was not sure that matching only at the start of a line was the correct thing to do - see my example data. Yes, if I ran Chopper on its own definition, it would mangle itself; I will fix that.

Comment: I'd expect that anyone setting up a source file with "macroes" like that in it would want to make sure that the "macros" were screamingly obvious, not tucked away at the end of a line.