# How to find and replace a certain part of a file?

Tags: python

I have a master file that's incredibly massive, and parts of it need to be extracted so they can be edited. (Think 100k+ lines here.) I have a script already to take parts out of the file, say I have

```
module 1
  module a
    module aa
    module bb
  module b
    module cc
    module dd
```

and I run the script and remove a, I get

```
module a
  module aa
  module bb
```

I want to know how I can add module a and all it's submodules back to the file after I make changes to it.

Similar to this: [python replace section of text with only knowing the begining and last word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071844/python-replace-section-of-text-with-only-knowing-the-begining-and-last-word) except how to add text back in at that point.

Comment: It's a littler hard more than a suggestion if one does not know the entire problem. As for the suggestion, seeing as you already have a script which runs through the file, create a new file and dump data in there as you go. If something needs not be edited, dump it. If something needs to be edited, do the edit and then dump it. You should be left with a file containing all your changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "insert into a file". That is not because python would be too stupid to include it, but because files in the file system are organized so that the only easy insert operations are:

- replace n bytes with n bytes of (other) data
- append data to the end of the file

I assume you do not want to load the complete file into memory (it is really an option, if your file is not excessively large) but you want to operate on the file. Then if you want to replace bytes n..p in the file by some other data, the steps are:

- copy bytes 0..n-1 from the original file to a temporary file
- append the new data (which replaces data between n..p)
- copy bytes p+1..(end) from the original file to the temporary file
- rename the temporary file to the same name as the original file

The last step usually ensures the change is atomic, i.e. if this crashes at some point, you have either the original or the new file in its entirety with the original name.

---

When it comes to the python implementation of this, the "copy from file to file" operation should be done in chunks. If you are short of memory, you need to do it with repeated `read` and `write` commands with a suitable chunk size (e.g. 10 MB at a time).

(If you process the file line-by-line, then this comes without any extra effort as suggested in Byron Coetsee's comment.)

Comment: I don't have any memory constraints, so I should be able to process the whole file at once. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Then it is easiest to just read the complete file into memory, and operate with the in-memory strings. One useful trick could be to make a list of pieces for your file, and then finally join it. For example `"".join([original[:n], newdata, original[p+1:]` (well, for only three parts: `original[:n] + newdata + original[p+1:]` is easier to read).